# Is there a halachic preference for milah over hatafas dam bris?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

While hatafas dam bris is clearly valid for a convert who is already circumcised, is this considered bedieved? Suppose a man who is not already circumcised intends to convert.

Suppose he is also considering medical circumcision for reasons unrelated to conversion. Or perhaps, suppose there is a non-Jewish surgeon whom he feels more comfortable with.

Would it be halachically preferred for him avoid the non-Jewish circumcision and just wait for giyur? That is to say, is there any halachic preference to him getting a full circumcision from a mohel *lechatchilah*, rather than going ahead with a non-Jewish circumcision beforehand with the intent of getting hatafas dam bris later?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82318/759 Can't he always say he changed his mind and then changed back? What does a "bedieved" conversion even mean? He's sort-of Jewish? Jewish lechumra?

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe I don't understand the concept of bedieved correctly, but I usually think of it being 100% acceptable after the fact, but not the ideal path when all options are available. 

Someone could arrange a situation where they are arriving at conversion already circumcised, and to the best of my knowledge that would not affect the effectiveness of the conversion. But that's not really my question.

In my limited understanding it seems like there are times when two paths can lead to the same result, yet one path is preferred if the option is available. Is this such a case or not?